# Prime factors of $5 n^4 - 70 n^3 + 380 n^2 - 945 n + 911 $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Let $n$ be an integer.
Then any prime factor of

$$ 5 n^4 - 70 n^3 + 380 n^2 - 945 n + 911 $$

Must be congruent to 1 mod 10.

Also

Let $n$ be an integer.
Then any prime factor of

$$ 5 n^4 - 10 n^3 + 20 n^2 - 15 n + 11 $$

Must be congruent to 1 mod 10.

How to prove these ?

How to find such identities ?

Comment: Better now lhf ?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: By factoring the first polynomial minus one we get, by setting $p(n)=5 n^4 - 70 n^3 + 380 n^2 - 945 n + 911$,

$$ 4\cdot p(n) = -1+5\left(2n^2-14n+27\right)^2 $$
so for every odd prime divisor $q\mid p(n)$ we have $\left(\frac{5}{q}\right)=+1$ and by quadratic reciprocity $q$ is forced to belong to some particular residue classes $\!\!\pmod{20}$. It is not difficult to show that $p(n)$ is odd for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and similar arguments apply to the second polynomial, too.

Comment: Ok but How did you know to multiply p(n) by 4 ???

Comment: @mick: $p(n)-1=5(x^2-7x+\color{red}{13})(x^2-7x+\color{red}{14})$, hence $4 p(n)$ can be written as $5 f(n)^2+1 $ where $f(n)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: Euhmmm confused.

Comment: I note that there are 4 residue relatively prime  mod 10. So do we always use 4 ? For the 911 polynomial too ??

Comment: @David: correct, now fixed.

Comment: Apart from the mysterious 4 I mentioned , I am surprised to see the form $ - 1 + 5 c^2 $ while I expected $a^2 + 5 b^2$ (norm) ... still confused.

Comment: Mick, the $4$ is nothing to do with the $4$ residues modulo $10$, it's to get rid of fractions.  In an earlier comment Jack is pointing out that there is a difference of two squares,$$(x^2-7x+\color{red}{13})(x^2-7x+\color{red}{14})=(x^2-7x+13\tfrac12)^2-(\tfrac12)^2\ ,$$and if you multiply by $4$ all terms are integers.